# Error using JavaScript SDK for AlexaForBusiness

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, alexa-for-business

Need help fixing the error I get, when trying to use the sample code below:

```
    var aws = require('aws-sdk');
    const alexaforbusiness = new aws.AlexaForBusiness({ region: "us-east-1" });
    
    export async function main(event, context) {
        try{
            var params = {
                UserId: event.body.uid,
                Email: event.body.email,
                FirstName: event.body.FirstName,
                LastName: event.body.LastName,
                Tags: [{
                    Key: event.body.tag,
                    Value: event.body.tagVal
                 },
                 ]
            };
            var cData = await alexaforbusiness.createUser(params);
        }
        catch(err){
             console.log(err, err.stack); 
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
err.message : Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Request'
|     property 'response' -> object with constructor 'Response'
--- property 'request' closes the circle
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-alexa-for-business/index.html) the async/await style of V2 SDK for AlexaForBusiness should work, but only the callbacks style of the API works.

```
const alexaforbusiness = new aws.AlexaForBusiness({ apiVersion: '2017-11-09', region: "YOUR_REGION" });    
var params = {
      UserId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
      ClientRequestToken: 'STRING_VALUE',
      Email: 'STRING_VALUE',
      FirstName: 'STRING_VALUE',
      LastName: 'STRING_VALUE',
      Tags: [
        {
          Key: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
          Value: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
        },
        /* more items */
      ]
    };
    alexaforbusiness.createUser(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
```